# How to apply Texture-Mapping to a Maya Object using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, maya, texture-mapping

I am currently learning how to map 2d textures to 3d objects using GLSL. I have a main.cpp, fragment shader, and vertex shader to achieve this as well as a Sphere.obj I made using Maya and some PNG images.

I just created a basic sphere poly model in Maya then exported it as a ".obj".

My fragment shader code is listed below for reference:

```
#version 410

// Inputs from application.
// Generally, "in" like the eye and normal vectors for things that change frequently,
// and "uniform" for things that change less often (think scene versus vertices).  
in vec3 position_eye, normal_eye;
uniform mat4 view_mat;

// This light setup would usually be passed in from the application.
vec3 light_position_world  = vec3 (10.0, 25.0, 10.0);
vec3 Ls = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // neutral, full specular color of light
vec3 Ld = vec3 (0.8, 0.8, 0.8);    // neutral, lessened diffuse light color of light
vec3 La = vec3 (0.12, 0.12, 0.12); // ambient color of light - just a bit more than dk gray bg

// Surface reflectance properties for Phong or Blinn-Phong shading models below.
vec3 Ks = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // fully reflect specular light
vec3 Kd = vec3 (0.32, 0.18, 0.5);  // purple diffuse surface reflectance
vec3 Ka = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // fully reflect ambient light
float specular_exponent = 400.0;   // specular 'power' -- controls "roll-off"

// These come from the VAO for texture coordinates.
in vec2 texture_coords;

// And from the uniform outputs for the textures setup in main.cpp.
uniform sampler2D texture00;
uniform sampler2D texture01;

out vec4 fragment_color;           // color of surface to draw

void main () 
{
    // Ambient intensity
    vec3 Ia = La * Ka;

    // These next few lines sample the current texture coord (s, t) in texture00 and 01 and mix.
    vec4 texel_a = texture (texture00, fract(texture_coords*2.0));
    vec4 texel_b = texture (texture01, fract(texture_coords*2.0));
    //vec4 mixed   = mix (texel_a, texel_b, texture_coords.x);
    vec4 mixed   = mix (texel_a, texel_b, texture_coords.x);
    Kd.x = mixed.x;
    Kd.y = mixed.y;
    Kd.z = mixed.z; 

    // Transform light position to view space.
    // Vectors here are appended with _eye as a reminder once in view space versus world space.
    // "Eye" is used instead of "camera" since reflectance models often phrased that way.
    vec3 light_position_eye = vec3 (view_mat * vec4 (light_position_world, 1.0));
    vec3 distance_to_light_eye = light_position_eye - position_eye;
    vec3 direction_to_light_eye = normalize (distance_to_light_eye);

    // Diffuse intensity
    float dot_prod = dot (direction_to_light_eye, normal_eye);
    dot_prod = max (dot_prod, 0.0);
    vec3 Id = Ld * Kd * dot_prod; // final diffuse intensity

    // Specular is view dependent; get vector toward camera.
    vec3 surface_to_viewer_eye = normalize (-position_eye);

    // Phong    
    //vec3 reflection_eye = reflect (-direction_to_light_eye, normal_eye);
    //float dot_prod_specular = dot (reflection_eye, surface_to_viewer_eye);
    //dot_prod_specular = max (dot_prod_specular, 0.0);
    //float specular_factor = pow (dot_prod_specular, specular_exponent);

    // Blinn
    vec3 half_way_eye = normalize (surface_to_viewer_eye + direction_to_light_eye);
    float dot_prod_specular = max (dot (half_way_eye, normal_eye), 0.0);
    float specular_factor = pow (dot_prod_specular, specular_exponent);

    // Specular intensity
    vec3 Is = Ls * Ks * specular_factor; // final specular intensity

    // final color
    fragment_color = vec4 (Is + Id + Ia, 1.0);
}
```

I type in the following command into the terminal to run my package:
./go fs.glsl vs.glsl Sphere.obj image.png image2.png

I am trying to map a world map.jpg to my sphere using this method and ignore the 2nd image input. But it won't run. Can someone tell me what I need to comment out in my fragment shader to ignore the second texture input so my code will run?

PS: How would I go about modifying my fragment shader to implement various types of 'tiling'? I'm a bit lost on this as well. Any examples or tips are appreciated.

Here is the texture portion of my main.cpp code.

```
// load textures
GLuint tex00;
int tex00location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "texture00");
glUniform1i (tex00location, 0);
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
assert (load_texture (argv[4], &tex00));
//assert (load_texture ("ship.png", &tex00));

GLuint tex01;
int tex01location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "texture01");
glUniform1i (tex01location, 1);
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);
assert (load_texture (argv[5], &tex01));

/*---------------------------SET RENDERING DEFAULTS---------------------------*/

// Choose vertex and fragment shaders to use as well as view and proj matrices.

glUniformMatrix4fv (view_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, view_mat.m);
glUniformMatrix4fv (proj_mat_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_mat.m);

// The model matrix stores the position and orientation transformations for the mesh.
mat4 model_mat;   
model_mat = translate (identity_mat4 () * scale(identity_mat4(), vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), vec3(0, -0.5, 0)) * rotate_y_deg (identity_mat4 (), 90 );

// Setup basic GL display attributes.   
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // enable depth-testing
glDepthFunc (GL_LESS);      // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"
glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);    // cull face
glCullFace (GL_BACK);       // cull back face
glFrontFace (GL_CCW);       // set counter-clock-wise vertex order to mean the front
glClearColor (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);   // non-black background to help spot mistakes
glViewport (0, 0, g_gl_width, g_gl_height); // make sure correct aspect ratio
```

Comment: Ok, so I got my sphere triangulated in Maya then exported it again. Apparently that was the initial problem. Now im struggling to get my code to run without specifying 2 images. What do I need to comment out?

Comment: I don't think we can answer all your questions without seeing your program code. Tiling is supported by opengl's [glTexParameter](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) functions, specifically the `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP` options. If you want to ignore the second texture then just comment out the `texture01` uniform, the `texel_b` texture fetch and the mixing, and don't set up `texture01` in your program code.

Comment: I commented all of those out but it still won't execute. It must be something in the main.cpp causing the problem.

Comment: Do you get a shader compilation error?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing any program code

Comment: Ive added the texture portion of my main.cpp code for reference now.

Comment: Whenever I try to run it, it says: Usage: ./go fragment_shader, vertex_shader, mesh_namefile, textureOne.(png/jpg), textureTwo.(png/jpg)

Comment: Sounds like your `main` code is expecting more parameter options. Have you removed the requirement for `argv[5]` being present at run-time? If you could append your argv parsing code that would probably help solve this